# If statement (without else) in tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I want to have an if statement in tensorflow; and if the condition is not fulfilled nothing should happen.

I tried to use both tf.case and tf.cond but both require a specification of a function it the statement evaluates False.

```py
op = tf.cond(tf.equal(x, y), true_fn=f1(), false_fn=lambda: None)
```

gives me an error: ValueError: false_fn must have a return value.

Comment: Not possible, `false_fn` must also return a tensor. What are you trying to do? Perhaps you are looking for `tf.boolean_mask` instead.

Comment: If ```tf.equal(x,y)``` is True, I want to print an output using tf.print() if not I don't want to print anything.

Comment: Are you using tensorflow 2.0?

Comment: No, Tensorflow 1.14.

Comment: Are x and y tensors or scalars?

Comment: x is ```Tensor("minimize/while/Identity_2:0", shape=(), dtype=int32)```and y is an int, e.g., 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On TF 1.x, I would use [`tf.no_op`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/no_op) to specify a dummy OP that does nothing:

```
ops = tf.cond(tf.equal(x, y), true_fn=f, false_fn=lambda: tf.no_op())
```

On TF 2.x, you can just pass `lambda: None` to `false_fn`, thanks to eager execution.

---

**Minimal Code Sample**

```
import tensorflow as tf

x, y, z = tf.constant(1), tf.constant(1), tf.constant(2)
op1 = tf.cond(
    tf.equal(x, y), true_fn=lambda: tf.print(x), false_fn=lambda: tf.no_op())
op2 = tf.cond(
    tf.equal(x, z), true_fn=lambda: tf.print(x), false_fn=lambda: tf.no_op())

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(op1)  # 1
    sess.run(op2)  # does nothing
```

Comment: This solution won't work if true_fn returns a value.

Comment: @MohammadAmin true but you can return a tensor too, say if your true_fn returns an updated version of an input tensor then your false_fn must return another tensor (e.g. previous state tensor)

Answer (score -2):

You can use tf.identy(tf)

namely

```
op = tf.cond(tf.equal(x, y), true_fn=f1(), false_fn=tf.identy(tf))
```

@see
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/identity

Comment: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'ident'

Comment: Op's requirement is to print/show nothing for `false_fn`. This will still return something.